# div floating on other responsive div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple online card interface, where a user has a profile picture and then some details of him below. However, for this to work I need the profile picture to hover above two `div`'s. These `div`'s are coded responsive with bootstrap and that's where it gets hard for me. You can find the mockup and the code I already have below:

[image]

**Code**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

    <!--Faded background profile picture-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>

    <!--White container for text-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this (it is a simplified version of what you are working on but should help you figure out how to get it working): **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/345LE/)**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="" id="little-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

.col-xs-12 { width: 90%; }
.col-xs-12 { position: absolute; height: 90%; margin-top: -45%; top: 50%; margin-left: -45%; left: 50%; }
.col-md-12 { width: 100%; background: purple; height: 25%; position: relative; }
.col-md-12:last-child { background: white; height: 75% }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #e6e6e6; }
div#little-circle { width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background-color: orange; bottom: -50px; z-index: 99; left: 50%; margin-left: -50px; border-radius: 50%; }
```